# Need help to write Map reduce in Python to calculate avg (unit_price) per item_type per country per year

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

Any heads up to calculate average using map reduce in Python.
Below is sample data:
[image]

Below is my mapper code:

```
import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    #line = line.strip()
    unit_price, item_type, order_date, country = line.split('\t', 4)
    print('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (item_type, order_date[:4], unit_price),country)
```

Comment: Your reducer is the one that should be calculating the average since the mapper only sees one line at a time... Also, pyspark can do this in like 3 lines, so why use mapreduce?

Comment: thanks for comment @OneCricketer yes pyspark does this job pretty easily but there was requirement in hdfs .

Comment: Not sure I understand. Pyspark can operate with HDFS data, is what I'm saying... In any case, please edit your post to show the reducer code